# Cant create ORC external tables on Hawq PXF

Tags: hive, ambari, hawq

I'm using Pivotal Hawq with ambari and now I'm trying to run some queries over ORC hive tables with hawq.
Previously I was able to create the external queries on pqsql using SELECT * FROM hcatalog.hive-db-name.hive-table-name distributed randomly;

But now everytime I get the error:
Exception report   message  java.lang.Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/io/orc/OrcInputFormat.

Can you provide some help on how to surpass this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have missed a step to update your pxf-profiles.xml file that's required after upgrading to HDB 2.2. Please see the instructions listed here:

http://hdb.docs.pivotal.io/220/hdb/install/install-ambari.html#post-install-212-req

Comment: unfortunatly not, i think ill have to unninstall and try again